Can I substitute whole eggs instead of egg yokes in lemon pudding?
Can I use 2 whole eggs instead of 4 egg yolks in a lemon pudding pie filling?

Without knowing more about the specific recipe you're following, I don't think anyone will be able to give you an accurate, concise answer. Could you please edit your original post to include the recipe?
